# How can I use Django built-in filters with Jinja2 using Appengine SDK?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, jinja2

I've tried several different ways a while ago, each of them gave a different exception, so I gave up and decided to manually write filters when I need them. But I'm missing the native escapejs and other useful but simple filters.

There are several related questions and answers, but as far as I see none of them gives a seamless way to implement this. I guess the main problem is that django filters routines are tied too much to the django environment.

Please answer only if you managed to use built-in django filters in the Appengine SDK environment, from my experience it's harder compared to a normal environment, as Appengine environment is limited

Comment: What have you tried?  And just so you know, you're not going to be able to use any of the built-in Django template tags and filters in Jinja2 templates.  Jinja2 templates look like Django templates, but have an entirely separate framework of tags and extensions.

Comment: I've tried directly adding them like this: http://splike.com/wiki/Convert_Django_Templates_to_Jinja2

Comment: For example, escapejs works great with this method, however floatformat throws:raise ImportError("Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable %s is undefined." % ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE)
ImportError: Settings cannot be imported, because environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is undefined.

Comment: You can try adding a settings.py with Django config, and pointing your app to it by adding env_variables in app.yaml (with linebreaks and indentation):

env_variables:
  DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'settings'

Comment: for escapejs, no one mentions this but, I guess xmlattr filter does its job perfectly, you just have to put the string in a dict: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#xmlattr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template tags in the Django template engine are simple functions that accept values and parameters. They can all be accessed directly in the source code.

This is output from IPython:

```
In [173]: from django.template.defaultfilters import  date 

In [174]: date??
Type:       function
String Form:<function date at 0xa2935f0>
File:       /usr/local/python/thor/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/defaultfilters.py
Definition: date(value, arg=None)
Source:
@register.filter(expects_localtime=True, is_safe=False)
def date(value, arg=None):
    """Formats a date according to the given format."""
    if not value:
        return u''
    if arg is None:
        arg = settings.DATE_FORMAT
    try:
        return formats.date_format(value, arg)
    except AttributeError:
        try:
            return format(value, arg)
        except AttributeError:
            return ''
```

Most of the Django-specific magic resides in the decorator (`register.filter`) and in the way that the language resolves calls when you type `{% load <template library> %}` in your template. Look for the definitions in `<module>.templatetags` modules. Built-ins are located in `django.template.defaulttags` and `django.template.defaultfilters`.

If Jinja2 has a way to define new template filters (which it probably does), then you could simply wrap handmade template filters to actual Django functions.

So basically, just create Jinja2 filters that point to the actual Django function definitions.

Edit:
If you do not have access to the actual Django functions, just copy-paste the source code and remove or adapt Django-specific stuff.

The `escapejs` filter is actually a call to this function in `django.utils.html`:

```
_base_js_escapes = (
    ('\\', r'\u005C'),
    ('\'', r'\u0027'),
    ('"', r'\u0022'),
    ('>', r'\u003E'),
    ('<', r'\u003C'),
    ('&', r'\u0026'),
    ('=', r'\u003D'),
    ('-', r'\u002D'),
    (';', r'\u003B'),
    (u'\u2028', r'\u2028'),
    (u'\u2029', r'\u2029')
)

# Escape every ASCII character with a value less than 32.
_js_escapes = (_base_js_escapes +
               tuple([('%c' % z, '\\u%04X' % z) for z in range(32)]))

def escapejs(value):
    """Hex encodes characters for use in JavaScript strings."""
    for bad, good in _js_escapes:
        value = mark_safe(force_unicode(value).replace(bad, good))
    return value
```

Answer (score 1):

I alluded to this in my comment, but I'll be more specific here since I have more space.  Django is an end-to-end web application framework, which happens to include its own template language, that for lack of a better term is just called the "Django template language".  All the template tags and filters in the docs are specific to that language.

If you choose to use Jinja2, you choose to use *that* template language's structures to the exclusion of Django's.  (Obviously the model and view stuff is a separate layer, but in principle, those could be swapped too--it's all loosely coupled.)  So the Django docs for templating are no good to you in that case.  If you want to format a float in Jinja2, it looks like you need to use the `format` filter, according to the [Jinja docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#filters).

Without more info, I really can't say what's causing your ImportError, but `floatformat` is not going to work in a Jinja2 template, so maybe that has something to do with it.